# Where to define Build Tags in Goland from intellij editor?

Tags: go, goland

In my go project various packages are used based on the go build tags e.g.

**with XXXX**

```
//go:build XXXX
// +build XXXX
```

or

**without XXXX**

```
//go:build !XXXX
// +build !XXXX
```

How I can define such build stage XXXX while doing debugging with **goland** , based on the debugging need e.g. with XXXX or without XXXX

Answer (score 4):

Go to Goland->Run/Debug configurations-> Go ToolArguments e.g. -tags build-variable-name

[image: define go build tags in Go Tool Arguments in Goland]

Comment: I specified globally in Settngs / Go / Build tags / Custom Tags and in the run dialog just checked the Use all custom build tags